# Parse value from string

Tags: python, parsing, parameters

I have:

```
url = 'http://example.com/json?key=12345&lat=52.370216&lon=4.895168&status=upcoming&radius=20&offset=0'
```

How can I parse the value `20` for the parameter `radius`?

I think it is not possible with `urlparse.parse_qs()`, isn't it? 
Also is there a better way rather than using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use [parse_qs()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

> Parse a query string given as a string argument (data of type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded). Data are returned as a dictionary.
>   The dictionary keys are the unique query variable names and the values
>   are lists of values for each name.

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs
>>> url = 'http://example.com/json?key=12345&lat=52.370216&lon=4.895168&status=upcoming&radius=20&offset=0'
>>> parse_qs(url)['radius'][0]
'20'
```

UPD: as @DanielRoseman noted (see comments), you should first pass url through urlparse:

```
>>> from urlparse import parse_qs, urlparse
>>> parse_qs(urlparse(url).query)['radius'][0]
'20'
```

Comment: This won't work if `radius` was the first parameter after the `?`, because parse_qs doesn't ignore the rest of the URL. Really you should pass it through `urlparse` first: `urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)['radius']`

Comment: @DanielRoseman didn't know that. Thank you, will include into the answer.